# Unable to get call stack in Windows

Tags: c++, windows

Why am I getting ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE error in case of the following code? What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <DbgHelp.h>

#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

void print_call_stack()
{
  HANDLE cur_process_handle = GetCurrentProcess();
  HANDLE cur_thread_handle = GetCurrentThread();

  CONTEXT cur_thread_context;
  std::memset(&cur_thread_context, 0, sizeof(CONTEXT));
  cur_thread_context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
  if (!GetThreadContext(cur_thread_handle, &cur_thread_context))
  {
    std::cerr << "An error occurred while using function GetThreadContext. "
      << "Error code: " << GetLastError() << '\n';
    return;
  }

  STACKFRAME64 sf;
  std::memset(&sf, 0, sizeof(sf));
  sf.AddrPC.Mode         = AddrModeFlat;
  sf.AddrStack.Mode      = AddrModeFlat;
  sf.AddrFrame.Mode      = AddrModeFlat;
#ifdef _M_IX86  // Intel Only!
  sf.AddrPC.Offset       = cur_thread_context.Eip;
  sf.AddrStack.Offset    = cur_thread_context.Esp;
  sf.AddrFrame.Offset    = cur_thread_context.Ebp;
#endif
#ifdef _M_X64  // Intel Only!
  sf.AddrPC.Offset       = cur_thread_context.Rip;
  sf.AddrStack.Offset    = cur_thread_context.Rsp;
  sf.AddrFrame.Offset    = cur_thread_context.Rbp;
#endif
#ifdef _M_IA64 // Itanium
#pragma message("fix me")
  sf.AddrPC.Offset       = 0;
  sf.AddrStack.Offset    = 0;
  sf.AddrFrame.Offset    = 0;
#endif

#ifdef _M_IX86
  DWORD machine_type = IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386;
#endif
#ifdef _M_X64
  DWORD machine_type = IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64;
#endif
#ifdef _M_IA64
  DWORD machine_type = IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_IA64;
#endif

  int count = 0;
  // According to MSDN, the sum of FramesToSkip and FramesToCapture
  // must be less than 63 in case of Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP,
  // so set it to 62
  void* trace[62];

  while (StackWalk64(
    machine_type
    , cur_process_handle
    , cur_thread_handle
    , &sf
    , &cur_thread_context
    , NULL
    , SymFunctionTableAccess64
    , SymGetModuleBase64
    , NULL
    ) == TRUE && count < sizeof(trace) / sizeof(*trace))
  {
    trace[count++] = reinterpret_cast<void*>(sf.AddrPC.Offset);
  }

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
  {
    const int kMaxNameLength = 256;
    DWORD_PTR frame = reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(trace[i]);

    ULONG64 buffer[
      (sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) +
        kMaxNameLength * sizeof(wchar_t) +
        sizeof(ULONG64) - 1) /
        sizeof(ULONG64)];
      std::memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

      // Initialize symbol information retrieval structures.
      DWORD64 sym_displacement = 0;
      PSYMBOL_INFO symbol = reinterpret_cast<PSYMBOL_INFO>(&buffer[0]);
      symbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);
      symbol->MaxNameLen = kMaxNameLength - 1;
      BOOL has_symbol = SymFromAddr(
        cur_process_handle
        , frame
        , &sym_displacement
        , symbol
      );
      if (has_symbol == FALSE)
      {
        std::cerr << "An error occurred while using function SymFromAddr."
                  << " Error code: " << GetLastError() << '\n';
      }

      // Attempt to retrieve line number information.
      DWORD line_displacement = 0;
      IMAGEHLP_LINE64 line = {};
      line.SizeOfStruct = sizeof(IMAGEHLP_LINE64);
      BOOL has_line = SymGetLineFromAddr64(
        cur_process_handle
        , frame
        , &line_displacement
        , &line
      );
      if (has_line == FALSE)
      {
        std::cerr << "An error occurred while using function SymGetLineFromAddr64."
                  << " Error code: " << GetLastError() << '\n';
      }

      if (has_symbol == TRUE)
      {
        std::cout << symbol->Name << " [0x" << trace[i] << "+"
          << sym_displacement << "]";
      }
      else
      {
        std::cout << "(No symbol) [0x" << trace[i] << "]";
      }

      if (has_line == TRUE)
      {
        std::cout << " (" << line.FileName << ":" << line.LineNumber << ")";
      }

      std::cout << '\n';
  }
}

int main()
{
  print_call_stack();
}
```

Comment: On which line of the code do you get the error?

Comment: @Mats Petersson I've got these errors in case of SymFromAddr and SymGetLineFromAddr64 functions usage

Comment: And you definitely HAVE symbols?

Comment: @Mats Petersson The errors description says that handle is invalid, so I don't think that it's really important that I have symbols

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time in the history of programming that the error you get doesn't EXACTLY match the actual reason something goes wrong. Assuming your process handle is still the same value as you get at the start, I don't see that it would be invalid. But I have seen many examples of error messages being "slightly off".

Comment: Or, perhaps you didn't do "A handle to the process that was originally passed to the SymInitialize function."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you need to call [SymInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  first.